# Is this segfault of GDB itself?

Tags: c++, linux, gdb

I have written a similarity join program and I am trying to debug it. However, when I type `gdb -q ./simjoiner`, the output is as:

> Reading symbols from ./simjoiner...[1]    15939 segmentation fault  gdb -q ./simjoiner

When using `gdb --args gdb ./simjoiner`,  I can get the following backtrace:

```
#34324 0x00000000004f28c5 in ?? ()
#34325 0x000000000055efe9 in ?? ()
#34326 0x000000000055ebd9 in ?? ()
#34327 0x000000000055f0c4 in symbol_file_add ()
#34328 0x000000000055f125 in ?? ()
#34329 0x000000000058472e in catch_command_errors_const ()
#34330 0x00000000005870ed in ?? ()
#34331 0x00000000005845ca in catch_errors ()
#34332 0x0000000000587454 in gdb_main ()
#34333 0x000000000045375e in main ()
```

Therefore I think this segfault is caused by GDB itself, not my program. I am using gdb 7.7 from the archlinux repo.

I have tried to compile my program on gcc 4.8.2 and clang 3.4, both the same result. I have also removed `~/.gdbinit`, but nothing changes. However, if compiled with -O2 enabled, there is no problem. If I compile an older version of my program, it also works well; but I have not figured out which modification causes this segfault.

Do you have any suggestions? Am I doing anything wrong or should this be recognized as a GDB bug? Thanks!

p.s. my program is available at https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9GlL8tebaU3eXdmVkN6WDR5Ykk/edit?usp=sharing ; you can type `make clean; make gdb` to test it on your machine.

Comment: [Report bug](http://www.sourceware.org/gdb/bugs/) to GDB.

Comment: If your program runs for long enough, try attaching GDB after it has started running, which will make it obvious which process is crashing.

Comment: downgrading to gdb 7.6.1 solves the problem; now I am sure it is a bug.

Answer (score 2):

In fact this bug has been reported long ago. See https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16752 . But I am surprised to find that it has not been fixed even on current git version.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This is a gdb bug. You can report this to gdb developers.